# Somar colunas em pandas por linha e selecionando comparativo por linha Qgrid

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as srn 
import statistics as sts

dataset = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/Data science /BRA 2020.xlsx')

dataset.head()

dataset = dataset.drop ('League', axis = 1)
dataset = dataset.drop ('Country', axis = 1)
dataset = dataset.drop ('Time', axis = 1)
dataset = dataset.drop ('Date', axis = 1)
dataset = dataset.drop ('Season', axis = 1)
dataset = dataset.drop ('PH', axis = 1)
dataset = dataset.drop ('PD', axis = 1)
dataset = dataset.drop ('PA', axis = 1)

display(dataset)

dataset.columns = ["Home","Away","G Home", "G Away", "Resultado"]

dataset.head()

M_G_Home = dataset[['Home','G Home']].groupby('Home').mean()
M_G_Home.rename(columns={'G Home':'M_G_Home'}, inplace=True)
dataset.head(20)
```

Tirei as medias :

```
dataset['M_G_Home']=dataset.groupby("Home")["G Home"].transform("mean")
dataset.head(20)
```

Tirei a média do time de fora

```
M_G_Awya = dataset[['Away','G Away']].groupby('Away').mean()
M_G_Awya.rename(columns={'G Away':'M_G_Awya'}, inplace=True)

dataset['M_G_Awya']=dataset.groupby("Away")["G Away"].transform("mean")
dataset.head(20)
```

Porem estou com dificuldade para somar essas duas colunas por linha e não deixa o resultado final .

[image: Imagem mostrando o DataFrame]

https://www.football-data.co.uk/brazil.php

Answer (score 1):

Importando as libs

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as srn 
import statistics as sts
```

Carregando os dados

```
dataset = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/Data science /BRA 2020.xlsx')
```

Excluindo as colunas

```
dataset.drop(columns=['League','Country', 'Time', 'Date',
                       'Season', 'PH','PD','PA', 'MaxH',
                       'MaxD', 'MaxA', 'AvgH', 'AvgD', 'AvgA'], inplace=True)
```

Renomeando as colunas

```
dataset.columns = ["Home","Away","G Home", "G Away", "Resultado"]
```

Calculando a média

```
dataset['M_G_Home'] = dataset.groupby('Home')['G Home'].transform('mean')
dataset['M_G_Away'] = dataset.groupby('Home')['G Away'].transform('mean')
```

Calculando a soma

```
dataset['S_G_Home'] = dataset.groupby('Home')['G Home'].transform('sum')
dataset['S_G_Away'] = dataset.groupby('Home')['G Away'].transform('sum')
```

Mostrando o data frame

```
display(dataset)
```